# Are Moira Rose's Wigs Actually Made of Real Hair?

Tags: realism, props, schitts-creek

In '*Schitt's Creek*', I'm fairly sure that Moira says that her wigs are made of real human hair.

Is this in fact true, i.e. are the props also made of real human hair? Is there any proof of this?

Comment: Hair donation for wig making is a pretty big deal, especially for people with conditions that mean they don't have their own hair.  Just google 'hair donation' to see the many organizations that accept this.

Comment: A very large volume of hair for wigs comes from India as a byproduct of ritual Tonsure ceremonies.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.
Expensive real life and movie wigs are made from real hair.

Synthetic ones have a kind of 'shiny and fly-away' quality that's getting better as technology & techniques improve, but they're not quite the same.

A couple of links - one movie-related, the other just from a wig blog.
[UpWorthy - The way experts create wigs on some of your favorite shows is enough to make your head spin](https://www.upworthy.com/how-wigs-are-made)
[SimplyWigs - Synthetic Wigs Vs Human Hair Wigs](https://www.simplywigs.co.uk/blog/human-hair-wigs-vs-synthetic-hair-wigs/)